# What does a diamond sign signify in UML class diagrams?

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

Consider the below two diagrams. The top one contains a plain arrow at the right end, and the bottom one contains an arrow with a diamond at the left end and a plain arrow at the right end. The [great book GoF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634988) has usages of  both of these two kinds of diagrams.

I want to understand what does the **diamond** signify in the second case, and which one of these two gives a stronger association between `Customer` and `Order`.

Is the `Customer` class responsible for the lifecycle of `Order` class in either of the two cases?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If there is **no diamond**, then we have a simple **association**.

If the diamond is **left empty**, it signifies it is an **aggregation**. This relation is stronger than a simple association. In this case a Customer aggregates Orders.

If the diamond is **black**, this means it is a **composition**, which is even stronger than an aggregation because the composite class cannot be composite by other classes. Its "life" depends on the container.

I think it's explained a little bit more clearly, at:

- Ezra, Aviad (May 28, 2009) "*[UML Class Diagram: Association, Aggregation and Composition](http://aviadezra.blogspot.be/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html)*"

Answer (score 26):

The customer and order is a "has-a" composition relationship because if the customer ceases to exist so does his/her order.  Therefore, there is a life cycle dependency between the container (customer) and the instances within that container (order).  When the container ceases to exist so does all its instances.

On the other hand, if we say a customer has a book.  In this case, we have a "has-a" aggregation relationship.  Because if the customer ceases to exist, the book is still available.

Answer (score 10):

It signifies aggregation. From wikipedia:

> In UML, it is graphically represented as a hollow diamond shape on the
>   containing class end of the tree with a single line that connects the
>   contained class to the containing class.The aggregate is semantically
>   an extended object that is treated as a unit in many
>   operations,although physically it is made of several lesser objects.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram