# using Class diagram to create baseclass in object oriented programming in python

Tags: python, object, oop, inheritance, class-diagram

I am new to object-oriented programming I need to write a BankDataWriterBase base class in the following program using the class diagram given in below to the code. I cannot understand the complete thing that the class diagram has, anybody here to know & explain to me what they actually saying using the class diagram

```
import pandas as pd

class ExcelParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = []       
    
    def extract(self, file_name):
        ra

here is the class diagram for the BankDataWriterBase class, i have completed the EXcelParser class but i dont know how to approach the BankDataWriterBase class 

[![enter image description her
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an ExcelParser we'll start from there, But first perhaps take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142000/10875953)

ExcelParser will have an attribute `config` which is a `List[str]` and the function `extract` which you already have. You will need to store an instance of a `BankDataWriterImpl`.

`BankDataWriterBase` will be the base of `BankDataWriterImpl`(<-- needs to inherit from the base class) and will have some attributes: `input_path, output_path and bank_identifier` And a function `write_file`.

`BankDataWriterImpl` will have an `extract_json` function with a string argument and no return. `BankDataWriterImpl` will also store between 1 and n `Tasks`(so a list of tasks).

Each `Task` will have a run function that has no arguments and returns nothing.

Finally if you want to denote types in python take a look at [the typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: please see and correct my updated approach

Comment: First define Task or BankDataWriterBase then after those 2 BankDataWriterImpl then at last ExcelParser. To inherit from a class in python just do `class BankDataWriterImpl(BankDataWriterBase)`. But your original question is solved and the follow up question isn't really on topic anymore so ask a new question if you still have any.

Comment: done robin could you explain bit more about that BankDataWriterBase class diagram

Comment: What you had in your code was correct, i really can't explain more then in the answer unless you have a specific question.

Comment: I have raised a specific question for the could you explain it to me
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672511/writing-base-class-using-python-object-oriented-programming'